# Chronometer format change to 0:0 to 00:00?

Tags: android, timer, format

i want chronometer star like this, if it is at 0:5 (M:S) i want like this 00:05 
this is the code i am using :

```
stopWatch = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chrono);
    stopWatch.setOnChronometerTickListener(new OnChronometerTickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer arg0) {
            countUp = (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - arg0.getBase()) / 1000;
            String asText = (countUp / 60) + ":" + (countUp % 60); 
            time_view.setText("Time : " +asText);
        }
    });
    stopWatch.start();
```

where i have to change for that modification..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [NumberFormatter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/NumberFormatter.html)

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("00");
stopWatch = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chrono);
stopWatch.setOnChronometerTickListener(new OnChronometerTickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer arg0) {
        countUp = (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - arg0.getBase()) / 1000;
        String asText = formatter.format(countUp / 60) + ":" + formatter.format(countUp % 60); 
        time_view.setText("Time : " +asText);
    }
});
stopWatch.start();
```

[Some more number format examples](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.text/FormatNum.html)

Comment: when i press button how to start from again 00:00

Comment: Well, everywhere where you set the text just use the formatter. I don't know anything about a button since you only posted that snippet.  Haven't used Chronometer myself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy and smart solution for time format 00:00:00 in chronometer in android

```
Chronometer timeElapsed  = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronomete);
timeElapsed.setOnChronometerTickListener(new OnChronometerTickListener(){
    @Override
        public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer cArg) {
        long time = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - cArg.getBase();
        int h   = (int)(t/3600000);
        int m = (int)(t - h*3600000)/60000;
        int s= (int)(t - h*3600000- m*60000)/1000 ;
        String hh = h < 10 ? "0"+h: h+"";
        String mm = m < 10 ? "0"+m: m+"";
        String ss = s < 10 ? "0"+s: s+"";
        cArg.setText(hh+":"+mm+":"+ss);
    }
});
timeElapsed.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
timeElapsed.start();
```